# Can't use function return value in write context - next() function

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm getting the `Can't use function return value in write context` error on line 122 of my code which can be seen below.

```
current($data['token']) .= " " . next($data['token']);
```

I've looked at the similar questions but most of them are due to using language constructs such as `empty` and `isset` like functions.

From what I can tell, next and current are regular functions and I'm just passing them regular arrays anyway which they are designed to handle.

The array I'm working on is numerically indexed but at this stage, redundant records have been removed and the array numbering must stay as is (can't renumber the array) until after this function completes as it looks for links between the remaining bits of data if they are adjacent.

Comment: `current` is the function in question not `next`

Comment: Hmmm, that would make a lot more sense, I'm guessing in this case I need to extract the numeric ID for the current bit of $data and then write to that instead.

Comment: I can't tell exactly what you're doing, but a simple `foreach` loop may help??

Comment: Foreach was my initial attempt but the difficult comes in that the array is numerically indexed but many of the results are missing (the data comes from a large string and unimportant words are filtered out). Of the remaining words, some of them should be paired if they are next to each other, determined by their index, i.e. 5 and 6 (if they are appropriate categories). But if I re-serialise the array, it will invalidate the pairing because the words may not have actually been adjacent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data['token'][key($data['token'])] .= " " . next($data['token']);
```

Comment: How can I have this so it changes the original array? Or would I need to write a new array to deal with this?

Comment: I think that should do it (untested tho).